# Calculating the range of a tough function

Tags: calculus

$f(x) = \frac{\sin(x^{-1.5})}{x+2}$

Sketch this function, give its domain and range and state whether the function is odd, even or neither.

So, I know what the sketch of this is, but I used a graphing calculator, so how would you work out the shape of this graph (it's quite obscure) without using a graphing calculator.

The domain of this is x > 0, which I can justify. BUT the range of this function I can tell from the graph is -0.5 < f(x) < 0.5. But, I'm not sure how to justify this either. If I hadn't looked at the graph, how exactly would I work out that this was the range?

Also, I believe this function is neither an odd or even function.

Comment: Calculate $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$.  You may need l'Hospital's rule.

Comment: It's obvious from the expression of the function that $f(x)\in[-1/2,1/2]$, and if $f$ is to take values near $1/2$ or $-1/2$, it's certainly near $0$ (otherwise $1/(x+2)$ is too small). Then considering $\sin(x^{-1.5})$ when $x\to0$ gives the answer. One may give explicit sequences $u_n$ and $v_n$ such that $f(u_n)\to1/2$ and $f(v_n)\to-1/2$ (with $u_n\to0$ and $v_n\to0$ of course).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut:  Nope.  $[-1/2, 1/2]$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Arg! Yes. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, so the logic is, as the domain is x > 0, as if you take x as extremely close to 0, you get roughly 1/(x +2) as 1/2, but that would also have to give sin (x^-1.5) = 1 or -1 for the correct range right? So what's the logic in determining what the value of sin (x^-1.5) is as x -> 0? And let's say this gives you 1/2, that explains why the range's top inequality is 1/2, but what's the logic behind the -1/2 argument, and vice versa if the answer is -1/2

Comment: $x\to x^{-1.5}$ take arbitrarily large values for $x\to0$. But then you can pick large values of $x^{-1.5}$ such that $\sin(x^{-1.5})=1$, and large values or $x^{-1.5}$ such that $\sin(x^{-1.5})=-1$ (the graph of $x\to\sin(x^{-1.5})$ oscillates faster and faster as $x$ gets closer to $0$).

Comment: By the way, you can't reach $1/2$ or $-1/2$, so the range is $(-1/2,1/2)$.